# Placing message in geoprocessing progress dialog?

Tags: python, arcpy

I am after a way on using arcpy.GetMessage to achieve the following message in the geoprocessing dialog result window?;

The above 4 datasets have been reprojected to: WGS Web Mercator (auxiliary sphere) and saved in S:\GisData

Does anybody know how this can be achieved?

---

OK, here's my attempt, which isn't currently working;

```
# Get the spatial reference
 spatialRef = arcpy.Describe(template).spatialReference.name

#Loop through shapfiles in folder and reproject
 for fc in fcList:
     fcspatialRef = arcpy.Describe(fc).spatialReference.name
     if fcspatialRef != spatialRef:
         arcpy.Project_management(fc, outFolder + "\\" + fc, template)
         projCount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(fc).getOutput(0))
     else:
         arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc, outFolder + "\\" + fc)

# Print shapefile Project results
     arcpy.AddMessage(fc)
# Get the count from GetCount's Result object
 msg = "{0} datasets have been reprojected to: {1} and saved in {2}".format(projCount, spatialRef, OutFolder)
 arcpy.AddMessage(msg)
```

Comment: I would not use `arcpy.GetCount_management()` - instead think about initializing `projCount = 0` and then where to place `projCount = projCount + 1` so that it increments each time the loop runs.

Answer (score 1):

I would put all your messages within the condition where the export is taking place.  Otherwise, you will get messages of fc names that are not re-projected or error on the projCount value if the condition is false and the variable has not been created yet.

```
for fc in fcList:
     fcspatialRef = arcpy.Describe(fc).spatialReference.name
     if fcspatialRef != spatialRef:
         arcpy.Project_management(fc, outFolder + "\\" + fc, template)
         projCount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(fc).getOutput(0))

         # Print shapefile Project results
         arcpy.AddMessage(fc)

         # Get the count from GetCount's Result object
         msg = "{0} datasets have been reprojected to: {1} and saved in {2}".format(projCount, spatialRef, OutFolder)
         arcpy.AddMessage(msg)
     else:
         arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc, outFolder + "\\" + fc)
```

Comment: Hmmm, while the script runs and produces the shapefiles in the outFolder, the arcpy.AddMessage(fc) and arcpy.AddMessage(msg) are not displaying anything in the dialog window.

Comment: The condition must be false, and skipping to the else: statement.  If the condition was true it would go into the if statement and produce the print statements.  Where are you defining the spatialRef variable?

Comment: @ artwork. I have included the spatialRef variable in my question and is written like this in my code script. The projected shapefiles are showing up in the outFolder but no printing of the names in window dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a string with three variables that you are trying to send to the progress dialog of the Geoprocessing framework.  I've made what I think are the variables show up bold below.

> **4** datasets have been reprojected to: **WGS Web Mercator (auxiliary sphere)** and saved in **S:\GisData**

I suggest that you use a Python variable to count how many datasets you have re-projected, as you reproject each.  Perhaps call it `projCount`.

You should be able to get a spatial reference name from arcpy.Describe() of a dataset.  Perhaps call it `srName`.

Perhaps call the folder variable `folderName`.

Then one (of many ways) to do the rest is:

```
msg = "{0} datasets have been reprojected to: {1} and saved in {2}".format(projCount,srName,folderName)
arcpy.AddMessage(msg)
```